# $F(n, L) = 2F(n / 2, L) + nL + n^2 log(n)$ and Master Theorem

Tags: runtime-analysis, master-theorem

I have the following recurrence: $F(n, L) = 2F(n / 2, L) + nL + n^2 log(n)$.
Am I correct in saying that $F(n, L) \in O(n \log(n) L + n^2 log(n))$?
I got to this result by bounding the $nL$ and $n^2 \log(n)$ parts separately.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You don’t really need the master theorem. If n = 2^k then the result is <= 2 n^2 k + n k L.